# Drag and Drop view outside of Recyclerview

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

What I want to achieve: I want to have a view inside a scrollable layout (`Recyclerview` with `GridlayoutManager`) with tiles (Views) in it. Dragging and dropping an item inside of the `RecyclerView` should adjust the position of the icon and swap with the other elements. When a drag starts, an icon above the `RecyclerView` will change to a trash icon and dragging the view to this icon will delete it from this `RecyclerView`.

[image: Initial state][image: Starting to drag View5][image: dragging View5 to trash icon][image: View5 was deleted and other Views moved along]

I tried this [excellent tutorial](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.ur3v2suru), but I didn't find a way how to handle dragging outside of the `Recyclerview` as the `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` uses only `Recycler.ViewHolder` elements as possible targets.

The method `interpolateOutOfBoundsScroll()` gives feedback if the view moves out of the boundaries, but will only give back the total size that is offscreen, but no coordinates. Also, trying to drag the view out of the `Recyclerview` always results in cutting of the View where it passes the borders of the `Recyclerview`.

Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are bound by the `RecyclerView` boundries. You have several options:

1. Make the `RecyclerView`'s layout height to `match_parent` and to be on top of your upper view (is it a `Toolbar`?) and add a sticky header of the same size and have an empty transparent layout. That way you could drag ther and see the item floating over there.
2. Instead of dragging an item to a garbage can icon which is located too close to a legitemate upper-right item, make a long click to select the item (and apply a signal like a check mark or a red mask) and make the garbage can appear and delete uppon click (and maybe allow multi item deleting)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The upper view is a `RelativeLayout` that contains some `Textviews`, `Imageviews` and also the `Imageview` which should turn into a trash bin.
I like your idea with the sticky header. If the trash `Imageview` is the only element in the sticky header and doesn't fill it completely, is there a way to prevent users from dragging the views to the positions next to the trash `Imageview` row? I will try this out right now

Comment: @Eve just dont swap them if the destination position is in the header

Comment: still thinking on this one, is there no way like with the classic approach from [Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) to define a drag shadow so only the shadow is dragged not the view itself?

Comment: @Eve you can add another view on top which will change to a shadow once dragged

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. I would still love to drag an item through a recyclerview, which results in sorting all elements and then drag it outside of this view to some place else. But then if I only drag an element that is lying on top of the recyclerview, elements inside the recyclerview will not adjust/slide to the correct position?

Comment: you should sync them both

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve this simply by set this attribute for the parent of the RecyclerView:

```
    android:clipChildren="false"
```

Edit: thank Adam Katz, I don't know why but sometimes you have to add this to the RecyclerView to make it work:

```
    android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Comment: wow I cant believe no one else has commented this.  

Just an added, it is helpful to add
android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"

Comment: How to handle drop to a View outside the recycler?